# Azure DevOps API | How to get or list TFVC type repository itself

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfvc

I have created a new Azure DevOps project with version control type as Team Foundation Version Control. It results creating a TFVC repository same as project name.

I also added a new GIT repository to project, so there are now a total of 2 repositories. As shown in screen capture, the first one "Test1-TFVS" is TFVC type repository.

[TFVC repository structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFSOM.png)

Now my question is that how to get the list of repositories for my project. I tried the Azure DevOps git repository API's but that only list git repositories, and skip the TFVC type repositories in the listing.

What API I need to use to get the TFVC repositories in listing?

Or

As there is only one TFVC type repository per project, so how to get the name of that repository?

My requirement is to show/list all repositories (including both git and TFVC type).

Thank you.